# Como enviar esse Header usando NUSoap PHP?

Tags: php, web-service, xml, soap

Pessoal estou tentando autenticar num WS mas não estou conseguindo, eu consigo conectar e gerar um token, mas ao tentar fazer outras operacoes com token recebido não consigo preencher o header e validar a sessao, veja o trecho do herader:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Autenticacao xmlns="servidoralvo.com.br/OperacoesPortador">
      <Token>string</Token>
    </Autenticacao>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CartoesPortador xmlns="servidoralvo.com.br/OperacoesPortador">
      <request>
        <DocumentoPortador>string</DocumentoPortador>
      </request>
    </CartoesPortador>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
$Header = '
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Autenticacao xmlns="servidoralvo.com.br/OperacoesPortador">
      <Token>' . $Token . '</Token>
    </Autenticacao>
  </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>';

$AHeader = $Client->setHeaders($Header);

$AParams = array();
$AParams["request"]["DocumentoPortador"] = "14238911996";

$Conexao = $Client->Call("CartoesPortador", array($AParams), '', '', true, true);

fPrintDebug($Conexao);
```

Ele dá erro de autenticação, mas não é o token, o erro esta na construção do header, pois esse mesmo token usando o Soap nativo do PHP funciona.

O detalhe é que no servidor que uso na web, não tem como habilitar o Soap nativo então tenho que usar o NuSoap PHP

Alguem teria uma dica do que pode ser?

Comment: Marcelo voce está querendo criar o wsdl direto do XML ? Por o certo usando NuSoap é usar o metodo configureWSDL que fica dentro do objeto $Soap_server... Se for isso me explica eu te mando um exemplo.

Comment: Veja só, eu fiz uns testes com o Soap nativo do PHP, mas ao colocar no servidor vi que lá não tem o Soap, o servidor usao um metodo de include, bem fui usar o metodo do servidor e deu uns paus porque está desatualizado, então pra não ter que ficar pedido pro provedor atualizar o servidor, estou tentando usar o nuSoap, eu consigo autenticar na boa, mas quando tendo usar as funções que requerem o Token ele não valida o cabeçalho... não estou sabendo como enviad a requisição completa, como coloquei no xml acima tenho que enviar o header e o body, mas pelo soap nao sei fazer.

Comment: Entendi cara no Nusoap não se cria o WSDL ou XML como está fazendo você cria um metodo e registra ele o XML é gerado pelo Nusoap nesse caso você precisa colocar o método que cria o token e registrar ele. Segue um CRUD que eu fiz com Nusoap, ainda preciso refatorar mas tenho certeza que vai te ajudar. https://github.com/satodu/Nusoap-sample. Depois que voce registrar basta entrar em http://localhost?wsdl

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta para ver se te ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal uma coisa simples que me consumiu muito tempo, mas do que eu vou consumir no WS rsrs, o header tem que ir assim:

```
$Header = '<Autenticacao xmlns="' . PORTNAMES . '"><Token>' . $Token . '</Token></Autenticacao>';
```

Que coisa!

Comment: Ola @Marcelo, já que essa é a resposta para o seu problema, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. 

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro voce cria um arquivo que vai conter suas instruçoes de SOAP como por exemplo server.php.

Dentro desse arquivo primeiro tem que ter isso

```
<?php
//Chama a lib
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
//Starta o Objeto
$server = new soap_server();
//Diz que ele tem que criar um wsdl ou XML
$server->configureWSDL("registerWithToken", "registerWithToken");
```

Agora ainda nesse mesmo arquivo você vai registrar os métodos disponiveis no seu XML.

```
$server->register("registerWithToken.generateToken",
    array("token" => "xsd:string"),
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'
    ),
    'urn:registerWithToken',
    'urn:registerWithToken',
    'rpc',
    'encoded',
    'Gera o token de login'
    );
```

Em a classe com o método.

```
     class registerWithToken {
        public function generateToken() {
            ... Código que gera e retorna o Token ...
            }
     }
```

E colocar no final..

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : 'teste');
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Nesse exemplo é apenas para um método segue um exemplo com mais métodos. E com mais informação.

Ele vai criar um registro de métodos assim -> http://papoinformal.com.br/prueba/2/new/server.php
E um XML assim ->
http://papoinformal.com.br/prueba/2/new/server.php?wsdl

O consumo pode ser feito de várias formas o exemplo que cria o arquivo acima é esse :
https://github.com/satodu/Nusoap-sample/blob/master/server.php

Comment: Hum... acho que fui infeliz no meu texto, me parece que entenderam que quero criar um servidor, mas na verdade só quero consumir um WS ja existente.

Comment: kkk.. Cara Soap Client é nativo tentou colocar assim 
$client = new SoapClient('http://papoinformal.com.br/prueba/2/new/server.php?wsdl'); 

??

Comment: https://github.com/satodu/Nusoap-sample/blob/master/service.php Olha o consumo da outra via Nusoap

Comment: Pois é @Dom Soap é nativo, mas eu não sei o que acontece com alguns TIs... porque o cara não instala o Soap do PHP em um servidor num momento que todos usam? Não entendo... no servidor que estou usando simplesmente não tem o Soap Nativo... o cara deve ter os motivos dele. Tenho que usar NuSoap, :(

Comment: Olha esse segundo exemplo que coloquei o consumo via nusoap

Comment: Então @Dom, eu consigo consumir o WS o que não estou conseguindo é enviar o Header que é onde envio o Token, ai o servidor recusa.